# C argv[2]++ vs (char*)argv[2]++?

Tags: c, char, argv

Why are argvs act odd?
Example:

This will work as expected, print the 1st character of the 1st argument.

```
printf("%c", *argv[1]);
```

This however will print the character that's in the ascii table *(aka "one bigger" represented as a number)* instead of printing the 2nd character of the 1st argument:

```
printf("%c", *(argv[1] + 1);
```

Slight modifications will do nothing, exact same result:

```
printf("%c", *(argv[1] + sizeof(char));
```

The only thing that helps is actually casting argv[2] to char*:

```
printf("%c", *( (char*)(argv[1] +1 ) );
```

Why is this happening? I kno that:

```
argv's type :=  char** argv
and argv[1] == *(argv + 1)
and argv[1]'s type should be char*
```

but apparently it is not, as I need to cast it? How is this possible? It is declared as char**, yet its members aren't char*s?

Comment: If you want to index characters, why not `argv[1][0]`, `argv[1][1]`, etc.?

Comment: You have a missing `)` in the second snippet. Perhaps if you fix it, it will work as expected. Update: And the third. And fourth.

Comment: show us real code with its surprising output,

Comment: The output you claim to get would be from `*argv[1]+1, not `*(argv[1]+1)`.

Answer (score 3):

The premise of your question is mistaken. This program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
  printf("%c\n", *(argv[1] + 1));
  return 0;
}
```

run with the argument `test`, prints `e`, not `u`.

Comment: I'll defer to your 6 years of experience here, but I didn't think that pointing out that the question was mistaken is usually an answer.

Comment: @Barmar it's not, but you can't do code formatting in a comment. I don't care if it gets deleted as long as OP reads it first :-P

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your parentheses and dereferences are really where you think they are.  If `argv[1]` contains `test`, then

```
* ( argv[1] + 1 ) == 'e'
( * argv[1] + 1 ) == 'u'
^ ^
| |
+-+- slight difference here
```